# I cant trigger the Help command ( discord.py)

Tags: discord, bots

```
@client.group(invoke_without_command=True)
```

async def help(ctx):
em = discord.Embed(title = 'Help', description = 'Use $help  for extended Info!', color = ctx.author.color)

em.add_field(name = 'Test 1', value = 'kick, ban, warn')
em.add_field(name = 'Test 2', value = 'howgae, kill, hack')

await ctx.send(embed = em)

client.run('TOKEN')

Comment: You didn't read the tutorial for stackoverflow... You should format your post and explain exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Could you please update youw question and format the code blocks properly. Also don't just post code. Ask a well-formulated question explaining your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "$help" in message.content:
      em = discord.Embed(title = 'Help', description = 'Use $help for extended Info!', color = ctx.author.color)
      em.add_field(name = 'Test 1', value = 'kick, ban, warn')
      em.add_field(name = 'Test 2', value = 'howgae, kill, hack')

      await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: thanks for that, but it still doesnt work

Comment: Could you please not only post a piece of code, but also explain why it should solve the issue?